# Dynamic shcema changing using coredata without user knowing about it

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

Hi I'm a newbie to objective-c Coredata

Here is the scenario.
I have a model say **Vehicle** with properties *name*, *noOfWheels*. I perform CRUD operations on this model in my app. On app launch, I make a service call to check if model changes. If there is a change in model, like
1) a new property *company* has been added to **Vehicle** model and
2) a new model has been added called **Company** with properties *name*, *country* etc.

Is there any possibility to programatically read those changes and change my schema without user knowing about the update?

I have gone through light-weight migrations in coredata but they say we need to create other xcdatamodel using xcode and then programatically change the versioning in the app.

PS: I don't want to re-release the app as an update. Want to do it dyncamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not impossible but it's far from easy. Everything you do in the model editor *can* be done in code, but it's going to get ugly fast.

- You can modify the model. Note for example that the `entities` property on `NSManagedObjectModel` is read/write, so you could change it. The same goes for the `properties` property on `NSEntityDescription`, etc.
- If you do change the model, you **absolutely must** make these changes before loading any data. Once you load the data, you **must** consider the model to be fixed, because your app will crash if you make new changes.
- If you change the model, you also must still use model migration. If the modified model doesn't match what's in the persistent store file, migration is necessary.

Core Data is really designed on the assumption that you'll have a fixed data model that won't need to change more often than you update your app. It expects that you can plan the data model well enough for that to work. If you can't do that, a couple of possibilities include:

1. Don't use Core Data, use SQLite directly. SQLite doesn't care if you update tables. Core Data is a convenience for many but it's not SQL, and SQL might be what you need here.
2. Rather than attempt to modify your data model in code, create a modified version and upload *that* to your sever. Don't tell the app to add a new property or entity-- have the app download a new version of the data model. You'll still have to do model migration.

Changing the data model on the fly like that is fraught with peril no matter how you approach it. Say you add the `Company` info you mention. What then? Your code doesn't know what to do with it, so what difference does it make that you even have that data? You can't make good use of the new data without code changes, and you can't change the code without an app update.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Tom. I have such requirement where I'm not actually writing an app for the end user. I'm validating whether I can use coredata for this scenario or not.